# Extract IDs based on difference in timestamp

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark dataframe that has two columns ("time_stamp" and "ID").

Example dataframe:

```
      **ID**                **time_stamp**
       1AB               2015-01-23 08:23:16
       1AB               2015-01-23 08:54:40
      25CD               2015-01-23 09:02:20
       1AB               2015-01-23 10:15:36
       1AB               2015-01-23 12:38:40
       1AB               2015-01-24 08:25:16
       1AB               2015-01-24 08:53:40
      25CD               2015-01-24 09:01:20
       1AB               2015-01-24 10:14:36
       1AB               2015-01-24 12:30:40
```

I want to remove duplicate IDs (keeping the 1st occurrence) if the timestamp difference is less than 3Hrs from the first occurence (keep ID which appears first) and want to keep IDs if the difference is greater than 3 Hrs.

Expected output:

```
      **ID**                **time_stamp**
       1AB               2015-01-23 08:23:16
      25CD               2015-01-23 09:02:20
       1AB               2015-01-23 12:38:40
       1AB               2015-01-24 08:25:16
      25CD               2015-01-24 09:01:20
       1AB               2015-01-24 12:30:40
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `first` to get the required difference in timestamp, and do a filter on the difference:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

result = df.withColumn(
    'lag',
    F.col('time_stamp').cast('long') -
    F.first('time_stamp')
     .over(Window.partitionBy('ID', F.date_trunc('day', 'time_stamp'))
                 .orderBy('time_stamp'))
     .cast('long')
).filter('lag > 60*60*3 or lag = 0 or lag is null').drop('lag')

result.show()
+----+-------------------+
|  ID|         time_stamp|
+----+-------------------+
| 1AB|2015-01-23 08:23:16|
| 1AB|2015-01-23 12:38:40|
|25CD|2015-01-23 09:02:20|
|25CD|2015-01-24 09:01:20|
| 1AB|2015-01-24 08:25:16|
| 1AB|2015-01-24 12:30:40|
+----+-------------------+
```